# Execlp function unable to find binaries

Tags: c, fork, exec

I'm doing a simple assignment involving pipes and exec, heres the code .

```
#include <apue.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int out[2];
    pipe(out);
    char file1[1024],file2[1024];
    int pid=fork();
    if(pid>0){
        close(out[0]);
        scanf("%s",file1);
        scanf("%s",file2);
        write(out[1],file1,strlen(file1));
        //write(out[1],"\0",1);
        write(out[1],file2,strlen(file2));
    }
    if(pid==0){
        int c;
        int cnt=0;
        close(out[1]);
        read(out[0],file1,1024);
        read(out[0],file2,1024);

        execlp("sort","sort",file1,NULL);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

The problem is, the execlp function doesn't find the sort binary,
i also used execl giving it the full path but it doesn't work.
It gives me the erros "sort: no such file or directory"
Exec never gave me this problem, what is it?

Comment: `out[0]` and `out[1]` are uninitialised values.

Comment: @WeatherVane They seem to be set through the `pipe` call.

Comment: The first read() reads `file1contentsfile2contents` the second read() reads nothing and blocks. (iff the witer has flushed, which he hasnt)

Comment: Is the `PATH` environment variable set such that there is an executable `sort` in one of its directories?

Comment: Try (from the commandline)`sort wtf` . Sort will complain: `sort: cannot read: wtf: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of the two `write()`s will not be separated; the reader just reads them as **one** block, with the two strings concatenated:

---

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int out[2];
    pipe(out);
    char file1[1024],file2[1024];
    int pid=fork();
    if(pid>0){
        close(out[0]);
        scanf(" %s",file1);
        scanf(" %s",file2);
        write(out[1],file1,strlen(file1));
        //write(out[1],"\0",1);
        write(out[1],file2,strlen(file2));
    }
    if(pid==0){
        int cnt=0;
        close(out[1]);
        cnt=read(out[0],file1,1024);
        file1[cnt]=0;
        cnt = read(out[0],file2,1024);
        file2[cnt]=0;

        fprintf(stderr, "about to execlp(sort|%s|%s|NULL)\n",file1,file2);
        execlp("sort","sort",file1,NULL);

        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

`./a.out`

input is: wtf omg

Output:

---

```
plasser@pisbak$ ./a.out
wtf omg
about to execlp(sort|wtfomg||NULL)
plasser@pisbak$ sort: cannot read: wtfomg: No such file or director
```

---

So, the message is *not* about the binary not being found, but *sort* is unable to find the *file* `wtfomg` which was passed as an argument.

Comment: i'm sure the file i'm giving it exists, and even so, why does it say that it couldn't find sort?

Comment: and i already cheked the two strings, they contain the two parameters i passed, it's not everything in the first array

Comment: Because  the name it uses differs from your file1 variable, see the fprintf() output from  my version of your program  (can't you read?) Note:different Unices could  give  slightly different error messages. *Where* did you check it,in the parent, or in the child?

Answer (score 0):

Locate the `sort` command in your setup. Normally `sort` exists in `/usr/bin/` path. Use this

```
execlp("/usr/bin/sort","sort",file1,NULL);
```

instead of

```
execlp("sort","sort",file1,NULL);
```

Comment: i tried and it dosn't work, the fact is that the PATH variable contains that path